How to select from two tables using LINQ statement?
[Route("Mode")]
[HttpGet]
public object Mode()
{
    string query = "Select Sum(c.total) as Total, Sum(h.Qty) as Qty, Sum(c.Amount) as Amount, Count(c.Item) as Count, " +
                   "c.Item, c.Model, h.Date From Cart c Left Join House as h On c.Id = h.Id Group By c.Item, c.Model, h.Date ";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    SqlDataReader dr;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult(dt);
}

I want to rewrite this code to use LINQ. My requirement is to write a LINQ query to fetch data from both tables.
House table



Id
Item
Qty




1
Apple
15.00


2
Orange
17.00


3
Carrot
8.00



Cart table



CId
Item
Qty
Amount
Total
Id
Date




1
Apple
2
2.00
4.00
1
04/07/2024


2
Apple
2
2.00
4.00
1
04/07/2024


3
Orange
5
3.00
15.00
2
05/07/2024


4
Carrot
4
2.00
8.00
3
11/07/2024


5
Carrot
2
2.00
4.00
3
11/07/2024



This is what l have tried
IEnumerable DataSource = (from c in _context.Cart 
                          join h in _context.House on c.Id equals h.Id 
                          select t1).ToList();

Expected output table



Date
Item
Qty
Amount
Total
Count




04/07/2024
Apple
2
2.00
8.00
2


05/07/2024
Orange
5
2.00
15.00
1


11/07/2024
Carrot
6
2.00
12.00
2




Your SQL query won't work as h.HarvestDate which is part of the GROUP BY criteria doesn't exist in the SELECT, probably is this a typo error for h.Date in the SELECT?

You should able to achieve the LINQ query (syntax) for LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY as below:
List<dynamic> DataSource = (from c in _context.Cart 
    join h in _context.House on c.Id equals h.Id into ch
    from h in ch.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new 
    { 
        Total = c.Total, 
        Amount = c.Amount,
        Item = c.Item, 
        Qty = h.Qty == null ? 0 : h.Qty 
    } by new { c.Item, c.Model, h.Date } into g
    select new
    {
        Item = g.Key.Item, 
        Model = g.Key.Model,
        Date = g.Key.Date, 
        Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total),
        Qty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty),
        Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total),
        Count = g.Distinct(x => x.Item).Count()
    }
).ToList();


thank you for your feedback. I have applied your code but l'm getting this error:  'IGroup<anonymous type string Item, string Model, DateTime?Date>, ... does not contain a defination for Item and no accessible method...'

Hi, sorry for that, the Item, Model, and Date are the group keys, hence should obtain it with g.Key.Item and so on. Updated my answer.

Thank you for your feedback. All of the line of codes work fine except ' Item = g.Count(x => x.Item)' The error message l get for this is "cannot explicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' and  an anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with sam name".

I have applied your "Count = g.Count(x => x.Key.Item)" update but l am still getting an error which read '' does not contain a definition for 'key' accepting a first argument of type '' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

May try g.Distinct(x => x.Item).Count(), this aims to have similar behaviour as COUNT(Item) in SQL.

Alas, you didn't give us a defintion of your classes, so it is a bit difficult to know the relation between Carts and Houses: is it a one-to-many, or a one to zero-or-one relationship?
I'll assume the following:
You have tables of Carts and Houses. There is a one-to-many relation between Houses and Carts: every House has zero or more Carts, everyCart belongs to exactly one House, namely the House that foreign key Id refers to.
If I'm wrong, and the relation is not one-to-many but one to zero-or-one, the principle remains the same: the Cart belongs to either nothing, or to the House that the foreign key refers to.
Your database seems a bit strange. Apart from that you don't follow naming conventions when defining your primary key and foreign key, it seems that data in the Cart table is also in the House table. Your database seems not normalized to level 1. On the other hand, it could be that House.Item and House.Qty have nothing to do with Cart.Item and Cart.Qty. Furthermore, a proper Database wouldn't have a column Cart.Total, as this seems to equal Cart.Qty*Cart.Amount
I think you have the following classes. I renamed some of the properties a bit, so it is easier to understand their meaning.
class House
{
    public int Id {get; set;}                 // primary Key
    public string Item {get; set;}
    public decimal Quantity {get; set;}
}

class Cart
{
    public int Id {get; set;}           // Primary key. used to be your CId
    public string Item {get; set;}
    public int Qty {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public decimal Total {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}

    // every Cart belongs to exactly one House, using foreign key
    public int HouseId {get; set;}        // used to be your Id
}

If you want to define Carts that are not attached to a House (yet), then your class definition is slightly different:
    // every Cart belongs to zero or one House using foreign key
    public int? HouseId {get; set;}        // null if no House attached

If you are certain that Total equals Qty * Amount, consider to change the property:
    public decimal Total => this.Qty * this.Amount;

This way, whenever you change the value of Qty or Amount, you don't have to update the value of Total. Buth hey, it's your database, it's up to you.
Back to your question
It seems to me that your SQL command will not produce your expected output. Therefor I cannot use it.
It would have been easier if you would have given the requirement in words. Now I have to make an educated guess.
Your example doesn't show a House that doesn't have any Carts. Are you certain that every House as at least one Cart attached to it?
In your example, properties Item, Date and Amount of the Carts that belong to the same House are all equal. Are you sure these values are all the same? Is it quaranteed that Apple 1 and Apple 2 have the same value for properties Item, Date and Amount? In my answer I assume that this is the case. In that case, for the Output I can take the value of any Cart.Date and Cart.Item and Cart.Amount that belongs to this House.
If I look at your expected output, I think you want the following:
Requirement
For every House and all its zero or more Carts you want one object. This object should contain properties Date, Item, Qty, Amount, Total and Count.

Date: the value of property Cart.Date of the first Cart of this House, or Default if the House doesn't have a Cart (null).
Item: the value of property Cart.Item of the first Cart of this House, or Default if the House doesn't have a Cart.
Qty: the sum of all Cart.Qty of all Carts that belong to this House. I see that your Output.Qty for Apple is 2. I assume that is a typing error, and should have been 4. Output.Qty is 0 if the House has no Carts.
Amount: the value of the 'Cart.Amount` of the first Cart of this House, or default (0.0) if the House doesn't have a Cart.
Total: the sum of all the values of all Cart.Total that belong to the same house, or default (0.0) if the House has no Carts at all.
Count is the number of Carts that belong to the House.

Note, that this definition is also valid if you have the requirement that every House as at least one Cart, or has exactly one Cart.
To create your required output, I use the overload of GroupJoin that has a prameter resultSelector, so I can specify my output.
IEnumerable<House> houses = ...
IEnumerable<Cart> carts = ...

var result = houses.GroupJoin(carts,

    house => house.Id,      // for every House take the primary key
    cart => cart.HouseId,   // for every Cart take the foreign key to the House

    // parameter resultSelector: for every House, and all its zero or more Carts
    // make one new object
    (house, cartsOfThisHouse) => new
    {
        Date = cartsOfThisHouse.Select(cart => cart.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        Item = cartsOfThisHouse.Select(cart => cart.Item).FirstOrDefault(),
        Qty = cartsOfThisHouse.Select(cart => cart.Qty).Sum(),
        Amount = cartsOfThisHouse.Select(cart => cart.Amount).FirstOrDefault(),
        Total = cartsOfThisHouse.Select(cart => cart.Total).Sum(),
        Count = cartsOfThisHouse.Count(),
    });

In words: from every House in the sequence of Houses, take the value of property Id. From every Carts in the sequence of Carts, take the value of property HouseId, which refers to the House that the Carts belongs to. Try to match the Id and the HouseId. From every House, and all zero or more Carts that have a foreign key referring to this House make one object, containing the following properties;

Date: from every Cart that belongs to this House, get the value of property Date, and take the first one, or the default value if there is no Cart at all
Item: from every Cart that belongs to this House, get the value of property Item, and take the first one, or the default value if there is no Cart.
Qty: from every Cart that belongs to this House, get the value of property Qty, and sum them.
Amount: from every Cart that belongs to this House, get the value of property Amount, and take the first value or default if there is no Cart at all
Total: from every Cart that belongs to this House, get the value of property Total, and sum them.
Count: take the number of Carts that belong to this House.

